# MYSQL return date format

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am writing the date to a MYSQL table and when I query the table using MYSQL Workbench the date is displayed as "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss". When I execute a reader, the format of the date from the table is returned as "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss". Why is that? Why is it not being returned as I stored it. It wanted me to store it in that format, why does it not return it in that format?

stored : 2018-11-20 09:32:23
returns : 11/20/2018 9:32:23

```
var mySqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM purchase_order WHERE purchase_order_number LIKE '" + cmbPurchaseOrderNumbers.Text + "'";
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new MySqlCommand(mySqlQuery, connection))
    {
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            //Iterate through the rows and add it to the combobox's items
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                lblPoNumber.Text = reader.GetString("purchase_order_number");
                cmbBillTo.Text = reader.GetString("purchase_order_bill_to");
                cmbShipTo.Text = reader.GetString("purchase_order_ship_to");
                cmbWareHouse.Text = reader.GetString("purchase_order_location");
                cmbVendors.Text = reader.GetString("purchase_order_vendor");
                txtPoDate.Text = (reader.GetString("purchase_order_date")).Substring(0, (reader.GetString("purchase_order_date").Length) - 2).Trim(); 

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What language is your application code in  ?

Comment: C# - sorry I didn't specify

Comment: I included full block of code - just in case

Comment: It’s not returned in any format if it’s a proper data type in the database. It’s a DateTime object which you can format into a string however you want to. Don’t get it as a string from the database.

Comment: Great stuff Sami ... I changed the GetString to GetDateTime and added a ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); - it displays correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mySqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM purchase_order WHERE purchase_order_number LIKE '" + cmbPurchaseOrderNumbers.Text + "'";
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new MySqlCommand(mySqlQuery, connection))
    {
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            //Iterate through the rows and add it to the combobox's items
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                lblPoNumber.Text = reader.GetString("purchase_order_number");
                cmbBillTo.Text = reader.GetString("purchase_order_bill_to");
                cmbShipTo.Text = reader.GetString("purchase_order_ship_to");
                cmbWareHouse.Text = reader.GetString("purchase_order_location");
                cmbVendors.Text = reader.GetString("purchase_order_vendor");
                txtPoDate.Text = reader.GetDateTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); 

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Get the date as a `DateTime` object instead of a String. Then you can format it as you want.

- MM/dd/yyyy    08/22/2006
- dddd, dd MMMM yyyy    Tuesday, 22 August 2006
- dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm  Tuesday, 22 August 2006 06:30
- dddd, dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt   Tuesday, 22 August 2006 06:30 AM
- dddd, dd MMMM yyyy H:mm   Tuesday, 22 August 2006 6:30
- dddd, dd MMMM yyyy h:mm tt    Tuesday, 22 August 2006 6:30 AM
- dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss   Tuesday, 22 August 2006 06:30:07
- MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm  08/22/2006 06:30
- MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt   08/22/2006 06:30 AM
- MM/dd/yyyy H:mm   08/22/2006 6:30
- MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt    08/22/2006 6:30 AM
- MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss   08/22/2006 06:30:07

[Click here for more patterns](https://blog.nicholasrogoff.com/2012/05/05/c-datetime-tostring-formats-quick-reference/)

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I did. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome @jeranio . If you can please accept my answer. :)